# setInterval and how it interacts with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've noticed when using setInterval() with objects, it accepts this:

```
setInterval(function(){auto1.increaseValue(s);}, auto1.interval);
```

Where auto1 is an object from a class.
However, the program throws an error when I put an object or object of an array of another object inside the function.
Ex.

```
    let index = this.arrayForItems.length-1;
    setInterval(function(){this.arrayForItems[index].increaseValue(s);header.innerHTML = s.value;}, this.arrayForItems[index].interval);
```

```
    setInterval(function(){this.item.increaseValue(s);header.innerHTML = s.value;}, this.item.interval);//Where item is the object inside object shop
```

But this works.

```
    let index = this.arrayForItems.length-1;
    let referenceToPurchase = this.arrayForItems[index];
    setInterval(function(){referenceToPurchase.increaseValue(s);header.innerHTML = s.value;}, referenceToPurchase.interval);
```

Why is this so?

Comment: What is the error? Could it be related to behavior of the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)?

Comment: Add a console.log(this) statement to each and compare the result.